# QML: NumberAnimation can't refer to its parent SequentalAnimation

Tags: qt, qml, parent, qtquick2

My code:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    property double angle: 0

    SequentialAnimation on angle {
        property int myDuration: 3000 // const
        NumberAnimation {
            from: -30.0
            to: 30.0
            duration: parent.myDuration
            easing.type: Easing.InOutSine
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error on the "`parent.myDuration`" line:

> ReferenceError: parent is not defined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`parent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#parent-prop) is a property of [`Item`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html), an `Animation` is not a visual item, it inherits from [`QtObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qtobject.html).

There is no property in `Animation` to refer to its parent animation group.
What you could do is setting an `id` to your `SequentialAnimation` and refer to this `id` in your `NumberAnimation`

Comment: There is actually a parent method, just not interfaced to QML. I've always found this quite silly, also the inability to nest `QtObjects`, since all that functionality is already present in `QObject`. Who benefits from inaccessible functionality?

Comment: The problem is that the `parent` "id" in QtQuick refers to the `parentItem()`, not the `QObject::parent()`.
Indeed a bit weird since this is QtQuick specific and doesn't make much sense in the generic QML context. Most likely a leftover/compatibility from when QML was only used for QtQuick in Qt4